# vb.net create empty column datagridview on page load

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

hi i want to define a column on datagridview on `page_load` events

how do i achieve this?

i've tried the code below

```
    dgv_beli.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgv_beli.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None

    dgv_beli.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect


    'DEFINE COLUMN MANUALLY
    'kode barang
    Dim colKode As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    colKode.HeaderText = "Kode"
    colKode.Name = "Kode"

    'nama barang
    Dim colNama As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    colNama.HeaderText = "Nama"
    colNama.Name = "Nama"

    'jenis
    Dim colJenis As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    colJenis.HeaderText = "Jenis"
    colJenis.Name = "kd_jenis"
    colJenis.Width = 120

    dgv_beli.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    dgv_beli.Columns.Add(colKode)
    colKode.ReadOnly = True
    dgv_beli.Columns.Add(colNama)
    colNama.ReadOnly = True
    dgv_beli.Columns.Add(colJenis)
    colJenis.ReadOnly = True
    dgv_beli.Sort(dgv_beli.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    dgv_beli.Rows.Add(colKode, colNama, colJenis)
```

but the `datagridview` stll empty

please, help me to fix this issue.. thanks before

Comment: Its work fine for me. Vb.Net or Asp.Net?

Comment: vb.net winform.. is there any configuration i missed?

Comment: i posted this code in form load its work fine for me